# Aumentar fonte do conteudo escrito no input

Tags: javascript, jquery, java-ee

Bom dia, pessoal sou novo em programação Java Web, estou desenvolvendo uma aplicação na qual desejo escrever em um input uma palavra, quero depois selecionar essa palavra e aumentar essa fonte, como posso fazer isso? Estou com duvidas :/

Meu select onde seleciona qual fonte:

```
 <select id="SelectAlterarFonte" class="form-control">
                                                <option value="12">Fonte 12</option>
                                                <option value="18">Fonte 18</option>
                                            </select>
```

Meu input onde vou digitar.

```
 <h:inputText value="#{frameBean.objSvg.valueText1}" autocomplete="off" id="AlterarTxto"
                                                     styleClass="form-control" tabindex="0"/>
```

E por ultimo. Quero clicar nesse botão e fazer a ação:

```
  <p:commandLink id="btn_close_users_modal3"
                                               styleClass="btn btn-default" 
                                               validateClient="false" process="@this">
                                    <i class="fa fa-floppy-o fa-fw" /> #{bundle['system.ui.label.save']}
                                </p:commandLink>
```

Comment: Mas qual linguagem você está usando realmente ? Javascript, jQuery, Java ? E nos mostre seu código.

Comment: Estou utilizando java, mais da pra fazer um javascript e chamar na pagina?

Comment: O que da para fazer nesse caso?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seria isso? Fiz com HTML e JS puro, adapte conforme sua necessidade.

```js
function alteraTexto() {
    var tamanhoSelecionado = document.getElementById('SelectAlterarFonte').value;
    document.getElementById('AlterarTxto').style.fontSize = tamanhoSelecionado + "px";
}
```

```html
 <select id="SelectAlterarFonte" class="form-control">
     <option value="12">Fonte 12</option>
     <option value="18">Fonte 18</option>
</select>

<input type="text" value="Texto" autocomplete="off" id="AlterarTxto" styleClass="form-control" tabindex="0"/>

<input type="button" value="Alterar" onclick="alteraTexto()"/>
```

Comment: isso mesmo.. muito obrigado